# Understanding JQuery UI Tab control anchors

Tags: jquery, fragment-identifier

The [jQuery UI Tab](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) control is made up of a ul tag containing anchor links that represent the tabs. Normally clicking an anchor with a hash href will cause the hash fragment to be appended to the url in the address bar. So how come no hash fragment appears when a tab is clicked? Is there a way to modify it so that it does?

From jQuery UI Tab source:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as I've not looked into the source of the tabs ui, but what I believe it does is send a `event.preventdefault()` for the anchor so that the default href does not fire.

You can go into the code, and check the area and comment it out and check. Or, if you just want users to come back to the right place, use the `cookie` function with the cookie plugin.

Also, if you want to open a page at a certain #tab anchor, just append the tab id to the URL like normal, and that tab will open on load.

Answer (score 1):

Check the source; Tabs returns false on clicks of the tab anchors, so it doesn't follow the link and update the hash. You could add a function to the `select` event to update the hash.

Comment: Right- forgot that returning false = preventing default events... Thanks